# Can't Export GLTF with alpha value animation

Tags: animation, transparency, gltf

I have an object with a simple animation that just decrease the opacity from 1 to 0. I have created the animation using the keyframe, on frame 0 right click on alpha (value 1.0) and  insertkeyframe, on frame 10 I repeat the process with alpha value 0.00. However when I export the model as GLB I see that the alpha animation is no longer there, I still can export position animations but no the alpha value. How do achieve what I want?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Comment: glTF only supports LocRotScale and shapekey value animations.